# Add delimiters at end of each line

Tags: awk, sed

I've a csv file like below.

```
id,id1,id2,id3,id4,id5
1,101,102,103,104
2,201,202,203
3,301,302
```

Now what i want to add comma(,) to each line to make all line with same number of delimiters. So desired output should be.

```
id,id1,id2,id3,id4,id5
1,101,102,103,104,
2,201,202,203,,
3,301,302,,,
```

Using

```
awk -F "," ' { print NF-1 } ' file.csv | sort -r | head -1
```

I am able to find the max occurance of delimiter but not sure how to compare each line and append comma if its less than max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F"," '{i=NF;c="";while (i++ < 6) {c=c","};print $0""c}' file
```

Output:

```
id,id1,id2,id3,id4,id5
1,101,102,103,104,
2,201,202,203,,
3,301,302,,,
```

Answer (score 4):

With `GNU awk` (as I do not know if this works for other implementations)

```
$ # simply assign value to NF
$ awk -F, -v OFS=',' '{NF=6} 1' ip.txt
id,id1,id2,id3,id4,id5
1,101,102,103,104,
2,201,202,203,,
3,301,302,,,
```

If first line determines number of fields required:

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=',' 'NR==1{f=NF} {NF=f} 1' ip.txt
id,id1,id2,id3,id4,id5
1,101,102,103,104,
2,201,202,203,,
3,301,302,,,
```

If any line determines max field:

```
$ cat ip.txt 
id,id1,id2
1,101,102,103
2,201,202,203,204
3,301,302

$ awk -F, -v OFS=',' 'NR==FNR{f=(!f || NF>f) ? NF : f; next} {NF=f} 1' ip.txt ip.txt
id,id1,id2,,
1,101,102,103,
2,201,202,203,204
3,301,302,,
```

Answer (score 2):

You are already using the variable `NF` which indicates how many fields there are on a line.

```
awk -F , 'NF<6 { OFS=FS; for (i=NF+1; i<=6; i++) $i="" }1' filename
```

We start looping at the first undefined field and set it to an empty string, until we have six fields. Then the `1` at the end takes care of printing the now fully populated line.  The `OFS=FS` is necessary to make the output field separator also be a comma (it is a space by default).

Answer (score 2):

Unified **`awk`** approach (based on number of fields of the 1st *header* line):

```
awk -F',' 'NR==1{ max_nf=NF; print }
           NR>1{ printf "%s%.*s\n", $0, max_nf-NF, ",,,,,,,,," }' file
```

The output:

```
id,id1,id2,id3,id4,id5
1,101,102,103,104,
2,201,202,203,,
3,301,302,,,
```

---

Or via loop:

```
awk -F',' 'NR==1{ max_nf=NF; print }
           NR>1{ n=max_nf-NF; r=""; while (n--) r=r","; print $0 r }' file
```

Comment: This is probably more efficient than mine because you aren't rewriting any fields, but perhaps it's a tad obscure. Maybe explain how the `printf` width specifier takes care of deciding how many commas to actually print? Also for a fully generalized solution the fixed sequence of nine commas is insufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Following `awk` may also help you on same.

```
awk -F, '
FNR==1{
  val=NF;
  print;
  next
}
{
  count=NF;
  while(count<val){
    value=value",";
    count++};
  print $0 value;
  value=count=""
}
'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows:

```
id,id1,id2,id3,id4,id5
1,101,102,103,104,
2,201,202,203,,
3,301,302,,,
```